# Вывод данных из LocalStorage и очистка от мусорного синтаксиса

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Прошу помощи- при выводе данных из хранилища последующей их обработке код выводит 0.
Код такой https://jsfiddle.net/p510tuoy/28/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
       <tr style="color: white">
      <th scope="row">Координаты (b)</th>
            <td> <div id="mod5" >отсутствуют</div> </td>
         </tr>
    <tr style="color: white">
      <th scope="row">Координаты (s)</th>
      <td><div id="moddd" >отсутствуют</div></td>
      </tr>
       <tr style="color: white">
      <th scope="row">Размеры</th>
      <td><div id="raz" ></div></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Название города</th>
      <td>      
      <div id="mod4" >отсутствует</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <th scope="row">Своя надпись</th>
      <td>      
      <div id="mod6" >отсутствует</div></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Шрифт</th>
      <td><div id="mod" >Lobster</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <th scope="row">Размер шрифта</th>
      <td><div id="mod2" >Крупный</div></td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
      <th scope="row">Ориентация</th>
      <td><div id="mod3" >Книжная</div></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<BUTTON id="but2"></BUTTON>
<BUTTON id="but3"></BUTTON>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#but2').click(function() {
 var jsonArr = [];
    var obj = {};
    var thNum = document.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
    var arrLength = document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;

    for(i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        if(i%thNum === 0){
            obj = {};
        }
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[i%thNum].innerHTML;
        var content = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML;
        obj[head] = content;
        if(i%thNum === 0){
            jsonArr.push(obj);
        }   
    }           

localStorage.setItem('myStorage', JSON.stringify(jsonArr));


    });

});
$(function(){
    $('#but3').click(function() {


  let obj = localStorage.getItem('myStorage');

  let s = '';
  for (key in obj[0]) {
     s += key + ' : ' + obj[0][key] + '\n';
  }
  console.log(s.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'').replace(/\t\t\n\t/g,''));
  alert (s.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'').replace(/\t\t\n\t/g,''))
    });

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `localStorage` вообще хранятся строки, не говоря уже о том, что Вы туда положили именно строку:

```
localStorage.setItem('myStorage', JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
```

Поэтому:

```
$('#but3').click(function() {
  let obj = localStorage.getItem('myStorage');
  obj = obj? JSON.parse(obj) : [];
  ...
```

Comment: Спасибо! Добавила obj = JSON.parse(obj); и все заработало!